# Starting fragment activity returns null - for getactivity in the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

Hell, Im trying to start a fragmentActivity by doing this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CircleListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("cats", cats);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

from another fragment activity and when I do that I get this in LogCat:

```
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at com.example.masterdetailsexample.adapter.SampleAdapter.<init>(SampleAdapter.java:30)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at com.example.masterdetailsexample.CircleListFragment$2.onPostExecute(CircleListFragment.java:84)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at com.example.masterdetailsexample.CircleListFragment$2.onPostExecute(CircleListFragment.java:1)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-02 22:54:03.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and when I test i see that the error is caused here `CircleListFragment.java:84` or                 `adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), devices);` - I've tested and I saw that `getActivity()` returns null. Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
public class CircleListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";
    private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
    private ArrayList<Device> devices;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    boolean paused = false;
    int index, top;
    private SampleAdapter adapter;

    public interface Callbacks {
        public void onItemSelected(int id, ArrayList<Device> devices);
    }

    private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(int id, ArrayList<Device> devices) {
        }
    };

    public CircleListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        paused = true;
        index = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = getListView().getChildAt(0);
        top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if (adapter != null && devices != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
                devices.get(i).setChecked(false);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                getActivity().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                getJSONFromUrl(Constants.DEVICES_URL);
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                Log.v("--", getActivity()+" | "+devices);
                adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), devices);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                getListView().setDivider(
                        getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.transperent_color));
                getListView().setDividerHeight(20);
                if (Constants.isTablet(getActivity()))
                    getListView().setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                else
                    getListView().setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

            };
        }.execute();

    }

    public void getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        try {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // get JSON data from URL
            JSONArray jArray = jParser.getJSONArrayFromUrl(url);
            // Log.v("--", jArray.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject j = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray arr = j.getJSONArray("devices");
                ArrayList<SubDevice> subDevices = new ArrayList<SubDevice>();
                for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject o = arr.getJSONObject(k);
                    subDevices.add(new SubDevice(o.getInt("id"), o
                            .getString("text"), o.getString("title"), false));
                }
                devices.add(new Device(j.getString("title"), j.getInt("id"),
                        subDevices, false));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            getListView().setDivider(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transperent_color));
            getListView().setDividerHeight(20);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(position, devices);
        Log.v("--",
                "IS CHECKED" + prefs.getString(devices.get(position) + "", ""));
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
            devices.get(i).setChecked(false);
            if (prefs.getString(devices.get(i) + "", "").length() > 0) {
                listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
                Log.v("--", "checking " + i);
            }
        }
        devices.get(position).setChecked(true);

        listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
        }
    }

    public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
        getListView().setChoiceMode(
                activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
                        : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    }

    private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
        if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
        } else {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }

        mActivatedPosition = position;
    }
}
```

And `CircleListActivity` class:

```
public class CircleListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        CircleListFragment.Callbacks {

    private Button proceed;
    private boolean mTwoPane;
    // private ArrayList<Device> devices;
    private ArrayList<Categories> categories;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    private ArrayList<Device> devices;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_circle_list);
        if (Constants.isTablet(this)) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        initActionBar();

        if (!prefs.getBoolean(Constants.DEVICES_INTRO, false)
                && Constants.isTablet(this)) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, DevicesIntro.class);
            startActivity(in);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean(Constants.DEVICES_INTRO, true).commit();
        }

         devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
         devices = (ArrayList<Device>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
         Constants.DEVICES_EXTRA);
        categories = (ArrayList<Categories>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
                "cats");

        proceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list_proceed);
        proceed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CircleListActivity.this,
                        TestSearch.class);
                intent.putExtra("fromDevs", true);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean("fromDevs", true).commit();
                intent.putExtra("cats", categories);
                // intent.putExtra(Constants.DEVICES_DETAIL_EXTRA, devices);
                if (prefs.getBoolean("set", false)) {
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    prefs.edit().putBoolean("set", true).commit();

                }
                prefs.edit().putBoolean("set", true).commit();

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        if (findViewById(R.id.circle_detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;

            ((CircleListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.circle_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
            Log.v("--", "circle activity tw");
        }

        // TODO: If exposing deep links into your app, handle intents here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int position, ArrayList<Device> devices) {
        if (mTwoPane) {

            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putSerializable(Constants.DEVICES_DETAIL_EXTRA, this.devices
                    .get(position).getDevices());
            arguments.putInt(Constants.PARENT, this.devices.get(position).getId());
            CircleDetailFragment fragment = new CircleDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.circle_detail_container, fragment).commit();

        } else {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, CircleDetailActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(Constants.DEVICES_DETAIL_EXTRA,
                    this.devices.get(position).getDevices());
            detailIntent.putExtra(Constants.PARENT, this.devices.get(position)
                    .getId());
            Log.v("--", devices.get(position).getId() + " }}");
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }

    private void initActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#e91a34")));

        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        // actionBar.setcu
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        // getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        // getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you call getActivity() in onActivityCreated() does it still return null?

Comment: if it is null then getactivity before the asynctask should not work.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin how do you mean?

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski does this line work? `prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(` if it is then `getActivity()` is not null

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin ah I think i know what you mean - let me try and ill notify if that works

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes It works that way, but now I need to move this code: `getListView().setDivider(
      getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
        R.drawable.transperent_color));
    getListView().setDividerHeight(20);
    if (Constants.isTablet(myContext))
     getListView().setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    else
     getListView().setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);` because it causes error when its in `onActivityCreated` in the postExecute

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski it is working now?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes, but read my last comment! Thanks for your comment you can submit it as an answer!

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin nevermind I've moved that code to `onStart()` and now everything is ok!

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski dnoe :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getActivity is not really `null` since you can directly use `getActivity().getSharedPreferences` in your `onCreate` method meaning it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

If `getActivity()` returns null in the `onPostExecute()` method, the fragment isn't attached. You'll need to perform a null check to prevent the crash and then look into why your fragment has been detached.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you expain me in code how can I do that? I'm not quite understanding the issue